# Binary search in C++ of Codejam Round1A ProblemA

Tags: c, binary-search

I think the code snippet in contest analysis is not correct, while(right - left >= 1) may fall into infinite loop. So I use > instead of >=. But it doesn't give the correct answer.

However, the code passes the assertions, which means left is the result and right is the bound .. I think my code does the correct thing, but ...

Here's my code:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include<cstdio>
#include<cassert>
#include<cmath>

int main()
{
  int cases; scanf("%d", &cases);
  for(int c=1;c<=cases;c++) {
    double r, t;
    //long long t;
    scanf("%lf %lf", &r, &t);
    long long maxn = (long long)((sqrt((2*r-1)*(2*r-1)+8*t)-2*r+1)/4)+1;
    long long left=0, right=1;
    long long re= (long long)t;
    while ((2*r-1)*right+right*right*2 <= t) {
      left = right; right *= 2;
    }
    //printf("%lld\n",maxn);
    while(left+1<right) {
      long long m = left + (right - left)/2;
      double tt = (2*r-1)*1.0*m+2*m*m;
      if (tt<=t)
        left=m;
      else
        right=m;
    }
    assert((2*r-1)*1.0*right+2*right*right>t);
    assert((2*r-1)*1.0*left+2*left*left<=t);
    printf("Case #%d: %lld\n", c, left); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question? I don't see any in your post.

Comment: Sorry .. I couldn't find out why my code doesn't work with large input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, `double tt = (2*r-1)*1.0*m+2*m*m;` is losing precision. `double` only has about 52 bits of integer precision.